# Extracting Column name from Twitter JSON File

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive

I am trying to analyse twitter data using hadoop. I have created a hive table according to the tweet i had previously. Now i have again downloaded twitter data and the problem is that new columns came up in that tweet which was not present in the previous tweet data. My question is that is there any way i can find the maximum number of columns for a tweet so that i can create a hive table for it. Helpless so far Kindly help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have tweets in json format then make table in hive using below query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
   id BIGINT,
   created_at STRING,
   source STRING,
   favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweet_count INT,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<
      text:STRING,
      user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
   entities STRUCT<
      urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
      user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
      hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
   text STRING,
   user STRUCT<
      screen_name:STRING,
      name:STRING,
      friends_count:INT,
      followers_count:INT,
      statuses_count:INT,
      verified:BOOLEAN,
      utc_offset:INT,
      time_zone:STRING>,
   in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/tweets';
```

download jar form http://files.cloudera.com/samples/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and add

```
ADD JAR /home/kishore/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

Comment: yes i have successfully created hive table using this query before and it is working perfectly but there is one problem the text column in the json file contains \n character which is creating problem when i put select query can you kindly tell me how to escape \n from the text column. Thanks

Comment: In case you have to clean before loading the table or another solution use'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'   from https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: regexp_replace(text, '\n', '') as text  this command solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any idea to get all the columns which tweet consists

I think you should use Storage formats which stores metadata internally like AVRO and update schema accordingly, so that you can support dynamic schema

Comment: yeah i will try it thank you so much for the help :)